# Normal distribution, find k for which P(-k≤Z≤k)=0.7850

Tags: statistics

Find k such  P(-k≤Z≤k)=0.7850
Help me with this problem, this is really getting me a headache, I tried doing it by tables (Because it's better), but it is really annoying and expense to doing it value by value, can someone explain to me how to do it in a logical form? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

If $P(-k < Z < k) = 0.7850$, then by symmetry, $P(0 < Z < k) = 0.3925$